# How to write below \bullet in Latex

Tags: pdftex, beamer

I have to write something under the symbol `\bullet` in `Latex`. Is it possible?
I'm using the class `beamer`.
Here it is an example of a frame:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Products Market\mbox{}\\ \footnotesize{where $p_{i,t}=u_{i,t}$, with $u_{i,t}\sim u[0,2]$}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item<2-> Credit Market \mbox{} \vspace{0.2cm} \\ \footnotesize{where \hspace{0.1cm} $\bullet_{bank} \xrightarrow{loan} \bullet$}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item<3-> Interbank Market\mbox{} \vspace{0.08cm} \\ \footnotesize{where \hspace{0.1cm} $\bullet \xrightarrow{loan} \bullet$}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

In particular I want to write "bank" under the bullet, whilenow it is only in `subscript`.

Thanks